# Divide 2 numbers without using / ,* or %

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, divide

Let's say we assume a=16 b=3

- First I am trying to find the x to which when I multiply 3 and then subtract is from 16 will get the min difference
- 16-3<<0 =>16-(3*1) -- 16-3<<1 =>16-(3*2) -- 16-3<<2 =>16-(3*4) -- 16-3<<3 =>16-(3*8)
- at x=3 while loop will fail
- res = 4 and a will become 4
- Now again while loop will start
- 4-3<<0 =>4-(3*1) -- 4-3<<1 =>4-(3*2)
- at x=1 while loop will fail
- res = 4+1

Please help me with the complexity as my time limit is exceeding

```
public class Solution {
    public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {

        if(dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int a = Math.abs(dividend);
        int b = Math.abs(divisor);
        int res = 0;
        while(a - b >= 0){

            int x = 0;
            while( (a - (b << x)) >= 0){
                x++;
            }
            res += 1 << (x-1);
            a -= b << (x-1);
            // System.out.println(res+" "+x+" "+a);

        }
        return (dividend >= 0) == (divisor >= 0) ? res :-res;

    }
}
```

Comment: One way to look at this is that while multiplication is repeated addition, division is repeated subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify the program would be to search for `x` only once and then reduce `x` by 1 every loop:

```
    public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {

        if(dividend == Integer.MIN_VALUE && divisor == -1){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int a = Math.abs(dividend);
        int b = Math.abs(divisor);
        int res = 0;
        int x = 0;
        while(a - (b << x) >= 0) {
            x++;
        }
        x--;
        while(a >= b) {
            int c = a - (b << x);
            if(c >= 0) {
                res += 1 << x;
                a = c;
            }
            x--;
        }
        return (dividend >= 0) == (divisor >= 0) ? res :-res;

    }
```

Comment: Still time limit is exceeding

Comment: Then there is only one further thing I can think of: storing `a - (b << x)` as local variable to not calculate it twice. (I edited my post).
Is there probably some simplifaction that you can make or similar?